# when I add constraint into my model, the values of vector are lost

Tags: c++, cplex

I have a problem when I use the cplex optimization studio with visual studio c++.
I have a class "node":

```
typedef vector<vector<int>> Matrix_int;
typedef vector<vector<float>> Matrix_float;

typedef class node {
public:
int nodenum;
bool decided;
Matrix_int full;
Matrix_float argmax;
} node;
```

I tried to add a constraint by following:

```
for (int nn = 0; nn < node->full.size(); nn++) {
    if (node->full[nn].size() > 4){
        IloExpr lhs(env);
        for (int ll = 0; ll < (node->full[nn].size() - 3); ll++) {
            for (int lll = 0; lll < (node->full[nn].size() - 3); lll++) {
                cout << node->full[nn][ll] <<"   ";
                if (node->full[nn][ll] =! node->full[nn][lll]){
                    lhs += x[node->full[nn][(node->full[nn].size()) - 3]][node->full[nn][ll]][node->full[nn][lll]][node->full[nn][(node->full[nn].size()) - 2]][node->full[nn][(node->full[nn].size()) - 1]];
                }
            }
        }
        Model.add(lhs <= (node->argmax[nn][1]) - (node->argmax[nn][0]));
        lhs.end();
    }
}
```

but the values of vector "full" before and after this constraint is different!! 
 and its elements change to 0.
the output of this vector before, between and after adding constraint is:

```
before:
{{4 6 7 0 0 1},
{6 7 0 0 1},
{6 7 8 9 0 0 2},
{4 6 7 8 9 0 0 3},
{6 7 8 9 0 0 3},
{4 0 1 2},
{6 7 1 0 1},
{8 9 1 0 3},
{6 7 1 1 2},
{8 9 1 2 1},
{8 9 3 0 1},
{5 3 0 2},
{6 7 3 1 1},
{5 3 2 1},
{6 7 3 2 2},
{5 6 7 3 2 3},
{6 7 3 2 3}}

in constraint:
{{4 0 0 6 1 0 7 1 1 0 0 1},
{6 0 7 1 0 0 1},
{6 0 0 0 7 1 0 0 8 1 1 0 9 1 1 1 0 0 2},
{4 0 0 0 0 6 1 0 0 0 7 1 1 0 0 8 1 1 1 0 9 1 1 1 1 0 0 3},
{6 0 0 0 7 1 0 0 8 1 1 0 9 1 1 1 0 0 3},
{4 0 1 2},
{6 0 7 1 1 0 1},
{8 0 9 1 1 0 3},
{6 0 7 1 1 1 2},
{8 0 9 1 1 2 1},
{8 0 9 1 3 0 1},
{5 3 0 2},
{6 0 7 1 3 1 1},
{5 3 2 1},
{6 0 7 1 3 2 2},
{5 0 0 6 1 0 7 1 1 3 2 3},
{6 0 7 1 3 2 3}}

after:
{{0 0 0 0 0 1},
{0 0 0 0 1},
{0 0 0 0 0 0 2},
{0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3},
{0 0 0 0 0 0 3},
{4 0 1 2},
{0 0 1 0 1},
{0 0 1 0 3},
{0 0 1 1 2},
{0 0 1 2 1},
{0 0 3 0 1},
{5 3 0 2},
{0 0 3 1 1},
{5 3 2 1},
{0 0 3 2 2},
{0 0 0 3 2 3},
{0 0 3 2 3}}
```

Can anybody help me to find the reason?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated to your question and problem, but in C++ all structure and class tags are already type-names, you don't need `typedef` for a class.

Comment: You should choose meaningful names for variables, something like `[nn][lll]]` is a total mess. Also `=!` at the deepest `if` seems to be a typo.

Comment: Looks like the errors have nothing to do with CPLEX, just standard C+ errors. Certainly the '=!' in the innermost 'if' is wrong: it will be assigning values not doing a logical test.  I am guessing you mean '!='